# To remove duplicate from an arraylist in andriod

Tags: java, list, android-studio, sorting, arraylist

I have a simple arrayList that is been populated into a listview i would like to know if it possible to remove duplicate from the populated arrayList

```
        tetClassArrayList2 = new ArrayList<>();

        tetClassArrayList2.add((new tetClass("Action")));
        tetClassArrayList2.add((new tetClass("Adventure")));
        tetClassArrayList2.add((new tetClass("Animation")));
        tetClassArrayList2.add((new tetClass("Biography")));
        tetClassArrayList2.add((new tetClass("Action")));
        tetClassArrayList2.add((new tetClass("Comedy")));
        tetClassArrayList2.add((new tetClass("Action")));
        tetClassArrayList2.add((new tetClass("Animation")));
        tetClassArrayList2.add((new tetClass("Crime")));
        tetClassArrayList2.add((new tetClass("Animation")));
        tetClassArrayList2.add((new tetClass("Biography")));
        tetClassArrayList2.add((new tetClass("Action")));

        tetAdapter = new tetAdapter(UploadTet.this, tetClassArrayList2);
        listView2.setAdapter(tetAdapter);
```

The code works fine but i want the listview to be repopulated with the duplicate removed on buttonclick so the arrayList can be something like this which be populated in the listview

```
        tetClassArrayList2.add((new tetClass("Action")));
        tetClassArrayList2.add((new tetClass("Adventure")));
        tetClassArrayList2.add((new tetClass("Animation")));
        tetClassArrayList2.add((new tetClass("Biography")));
        tetClassArrayList2.add((new tetClass("Comedy")));
        tetClassArrayList2.add((new tetClass("Crime")));
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried?

Comment: Why not use a set ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to make sure `TestClass` has `equals` and `hashCode` implemented.

```
public class TestClass {

    private String name;

    public TestClass(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
      if (this == o) return true;
      if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
      TestClass testClass = (TestClass) o;
      return Objects.equals(name, testClass.name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
      return Objects.hash(name);
    }

    //other getters & setters
}
```

Now, you can use `distinct` from `stream` API.

```
List<TestClass> list = list.stream()
  .distinct()
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or you can do like this

```
List<TestClass> list = new ArrayList<>(new HashSet<>(list));
```

Example :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<TestClass> list = new ArrayList<>();

    list.add((new TestClass("Action")));
    list.add((new TestClass("Adventure")));
    list.add((new TestClass("Action")));

    list = list.stream()
             .distinct()
             .collect(Collectors.toList());

}
```

Comment: ok how do i use either of the options in relation to the code i already have besides where is the list coming from is it an arrayList or the listview.Please show a complete code like how to make tetClass has equals and hashCode method for the second option